# How to use PSQL_EDITOR_LINENUMBER_ARG in Windows version of postgresql

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

wondering around psql.

```
postgres-# \ev staff_list 2

environment variable PSQL_EDITOR_LINENUMBER_ARG must be set to specify a line number
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS

as the psql cli shows, in order to execute  `\ev staff_list 2` I need know about PSQL_EDITOR_LINENUMBER_ARG.
But I don't know how to set environment variable: PSQL_EDITOR_LINENUMBER_ARG.
So how to make `\ev staff_list 2` works in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL defines a default editor in `src/bin/psql/settings.h`: for Windows, that is `notepad.exe`, everywhere else it is `vi`.

Now `vi` has an option to start the editor with the cursor on a certain line:

```
vi +10 myfile
```

But `notepad.exe` has no such option, hence the error message.

You have two things you can do:

1. don't try to place the cursor on a specific line in the editor:

   ```
   \ev staff_list
   ```
2. Use a different editor and tell it how to position the cursor:

   ```sh
   SET PSQL_EDITOR=vim.exe
   SET PSQL_EDITOR_LINENUMBER_ARG="+"
   psql -c "\ev staff_list 2"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this in Linux, too (Ubuntu, to be specific).

@Laurenz Albe is spot on with [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108211/584940); just a few more points I think might be worth adding.

- Using `\ef` with `[ line_number ]` is the **only reliable way** I have found to actually get to *the line causing* the problem.  If I jump to line 39 in my (vim) editor, I'm usually a few lines too early<sup>1</sup>.    So, I've found it invaluable.
- From *within* psql, you can just use psql's `\setenv`
  `\setenv PSQL_EDITOR_LINENUMBER_ARG "+"`
- In psql 13.9, if you don't have `PSQL_EDITOR` set, you get a list of options:

  > Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  > 1 /usr/bin/nedit
  > 2 /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  > 3 /usr/bin/vim.basic
  > 4 /usr/bin/vim.tiny
  > 5 /usr/bin/emacs
  > 6 /bin/ed
  >
  > Choose 1-6 [2]: 3

  So, it will default to `nano` if you're not paying close attention, and wanted vim.
- When you `\q`uit vim, you are at the continuation-line prompt (`->`).  A semicolon will run the function as you just edited it; <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> will abort.  (Usual psql behavior, but not quite intuitive after the `\ef` finishes.)

---

<sup>1</sup> I presume PostgreSQL is not counting some blank lines or comments in my source, or it's changing wrapping, so that the lines it's executing are shifted slightly from my source code.